# Setting a jScrollPane to autoscroll left and right, but pause on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-jscrollpane

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RJShm/

I have a jScrollPane that currently scroll from left, to right, then back left, and stops. What I'd like is for this to continually scroll from left to right, the right to left, then repeat. I have this fairly close to working by using `pane.bind('jsp-scroll-x'...`, but I can't seem to get it to scroll back to the right after one cycle. Current code for that:

```
pane.bind('jsp-scroll-x', function (event, pos_x, at_left, at_right) {
  if (at_right)
  {
    api.scrollToX(0);
    $(this).unbind(event);
  }
});
```

I would also like for this to stop autoscrolling when anything in the pane is clicked (scroll bar, arrows, content, anything), and it would preferably restart after a few seconds of no clicks.

So, in short, how do I:

1. Make the jScrollPane scroll left/right automatically
2. Stop autoscrolling when clicked
3. Restart autoscrolling after a few seconds of no clicks inside the pane

Thanks

**EDIT**: [jScrollPane Settings](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/settings.html), and [api](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/api.html) for your convenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated the handler for toggling the infinite scroll and also implemented click handler to pause the scroll and resume after a timeout (5 seconds). See draft code below and check the **DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/p6jLt/

```
var defaultSettings = {
    showArrows: true,
    animateScroll: true,
    animateDuration: 5000
},
pauseSettings = {
    showArrows: true,
    animateScroll: false
};

var pane = $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane(defaultSettings);

var api = pane.data('jsp');
var isFirst = true,
    posX = 0,
    isLeft = false,
    timer;

pane.bind('jsp-scroll-x', scrollFx)
    .mousedown(function () {

    //lets make sure the below is
    //executed only once after automatic croll
    if (posX != -1) {
        $(this).unbind('jsp-scroll-x');
        api.scrollToX(posX);
        api.reinitialise(pauseSettings); //no animation
        posX = -1;
    }
}).mouseup(function () {
    clearTimeout(timer); //clear any previous timer
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
        isFirst = true;
        posX = 0; //reset the killer switch
        api.reinitialise(defaultSettings); //animateed scroll
        pane.bind('jsp-scroll-x', scrollFx); //rebind
        api.scrollToX(isLeft ? 0 : api.getContentWidth()); //resume scroll
    }, 5000);
});

var scroll = api.scrollToX(api.getContentWidth());

function scrollFx(event, pos_x, at_left, at_right) {
    if (posX == -1) { //kill scroll
        $(this).unbind(event);
        return false;
    }

    if (at_right) {
        api.scrollToX(0);
        isLeft = true; //used for restart
    } else if (at_left && !isFirst) {
        api.scrollToX(api.getContentWidth());
        isLeft = false; //used for restart
    }
    isFirst = false;
    posX = pos_x;
}
```

**Issues:** The plugin is little buggy with scroll sometimes, but it doesn't break the infinite scroll. You may find the little hicks on scroll, but it works for the most part. Test it out thoroughly and see how it goes.

Comment: This is very close to what I was looking for, but it's not behaving quite as I had hoped with the click. What I would ideally like is when the scrollbar is clicked (so it can be dragged) or the left/right arrows are clicked, the animation also stops and the behaves as a normal scrollbar would until the autoscroll went back into effect. Any way to do this?

Comment: @Samsquanch The plugin doesn't seems to be meant for these features. We are writing trick code to get the expected behavior out of that plugin. Let me spend sometime tomorrow to see how it goes.

Comment: @Samsquanch Yea, I found it a little problematic. I recommend writing a plugin as it would be easier to do.

Comment: That may be the ideal solution. This was one of those cases of "we want this" which turned into "we want this, plus all that stacked on top of it". The plugin originally accomplished 'this' perfectly, but it doesn't seem adaptable enough to accomplish the 'that'.

Comment: @Samsquanch ahh I see, I have been there.